# Variance–covariance matrix in meta-analysis of variation metafor

Tags: r, variance, meta-analysis, covariance-matrix

I'm conducting a meta-analysis on estimating a gold standard measure from other simpler measures. To determine the error of estimation, I derived the standard deviations of the differences between the two measures. Therefore, as effect sizes, I'm using the natural logarithm of the standard deviations of the differences $(lnSD)$ and their sampling variance $(1/2[n-1])$, as described on [Nakagawa et al](https://besjournals.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1111/2041-210X.12309).

However, many studies included in my analysis, the same subject produces multiple results (multiple estimates [stages in the data.frame below]). Thus, I should determine the variance-covariance matrix of the effects. However, I am not sure if it is appropriate to determine the variance-covariance matrix using any correlation value for this type of effect, because effects variances are based only on the sample size $(1/2[n-1])$.

Is there any alternative to determine the variance-covariance matrix for this type of data, or I should just include the study as a random effect?

```
    study    yi     vi exercise stage
1      A 2.351 0.0250      row     3
2      A 2.351 0.0250      row     4
3      A 2.261 0.0250      row     5
4      A 1.922 0.0250      row     7
5      A 1.887 0.0250      row    10
6      B 1.884 0.0313    cycle     3
7      B 1.851 0.0313    cycle     4
8      B 1.774 0.0313    cycle     7
9      B 1.740 0.0313    cycle    10
10     C 1.831 0.0278    cycle     3
11     D 1.732 0.0294      run     5
```

Comment: There is a package called metavcov that computes variance covariance matrix

Comment: See the metavcov vegnette using link [metavcov](https://luminwin.github.io/metavcov/articles/intro.html)

Answer (score 2):

Professor Wolfgang Viechtbauer answered this question on the [R help listserv for meta analysis](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-meta-analysis/2019-July/001622.html).  The covariance between two $\ln(SD)$ is calculated as $r^2/(2(n-1))$; where $r$ is the correlation between the two variables.